# Binding List<T> to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to bind `List<T>` to `DataGridView`. Everything seemed to be ok before I implemented deleting rows:

```
Companies.CompaniesList.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
dataGridView1.DataSource = Companies.CompaniesList;
```

(Companies.Companies is `List<Company>` collection)
What I've got is data error message (although row was deleted successfully). I tried this:

```
Companies.CompaniesList.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = Companies.CompaniesList;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

It works as expected. The question is: why?

Comment: what error did you get for first attempt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is common for property changes (via `set`) to detect and ignore changes that do nothing, so in the line:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Companies.CompaniesList;
```

I expect that `DataSource` is **already** `Companies.CompaniesList`, so **nothing** happened. No code executed except to test the reference. Checking in reflector confirms this (`DataGridView.DataSource`):

```
set
{
    if (value != this.DataSource)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So it only does **anything** when the reference is updated.

Additionally, since `List<T>` doesn't implement the necessary binding interfaces, the grid has no idea that the list contents have been changed, hence the error. Now contrast:

```
bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = Companies.CompaniesList;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Here, the `DataSource` **has** changed, as `bs` is an entirely new object. This causes the entire grid to rebind.

Another option is to use `BindingList<T>`, or to remove from the `BindingSource` (rather than the `List<T>`) which should operate in both directions.